# Removed python3, cannot bring back Gnome desktop

Tags: debian, gnome, cinnamon, debian-stretch

I accidentally did `apt-get remove python3` and didn't look at packages APT was about to remove.

Then Gnome Desktop Environment started to misbehave, I rebooted and it ended up in tty1 with no GUI.

I installed lightdm (just what found first in internet), it complained after I typed password `Failed to load session "cinnamon"`. I installed cinnamon. GUI appeared but it was, of course, Cinnamon not Gnome.

Then I googled more and installed gdm3 and gnome but I'm still in Cinnamon desktop and don't know how to get from it to Gnome.

In `sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager` I don't see Gnome.

I tried to remove cinnamon and ended up with same `Failed to load session "cinnamon"` on login.

Tried to purge and reinstall, but no success.

How do I get Gnome desktop environment back?

Answer (score 1):

There was Gnome set in

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

*I was 10 minutes before I found the solution. Just looked into `/etc/alternatives/`.*